# Android speech recognition callback with buffer

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I've realized that Android speech recognition does not send data as buffer to the listener as documentation says, so, I have read about Speech Recognition Service, that has a callback where it do send the buffer listened as real time but I don't know how can I instantiate the service from the activity to having an instance of it and pass the activity itself as a custom listener to be notified about onBufferReceived successfully.
Does anyone have an example of it?
Thanks

Comment: Hi colymore, Did you find any solution for this. Please write it here.

Comment: Nope, sorry, i readed something related to instantiate this as a service instead use listener but it didn't work.